How do I add an activation function at the last classification layer?
My model:
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.network = torchvision.models.resnet18()
        num_ftrs = self.network.fc.in_features
        self.network.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 19)
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        return self.network(xb)

How can I add a Softmax activation function at the last classification layer

Just add nn.Softmax() in your forward function. But the dimension is also important which you should consider in your code:
class ResNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.network = torchvision.models.resnet18()
        num_ftrs = self.network.fc.in_features
        self.network.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 19)
        self.act_fun = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)
        
    def forward(self, xb):
        x = self.network(xb)
        x = self.act_fun(x)
        return x


I would say that the last classification layer (fc) begin with softmax. So I would add an anctivation function and not a layer.
